# How should I configure Travis-CI for an Android library?

Tags: android, travis-ci

I am developing an Android library ([RateMyApp](https://github.com/mariosangiorgio/RateMyApp), which you can find on GitHub) but I can't see how I should setup [Travis CI](http://travis-ci.org) to build it every time I push new code.

The `.travis.yml` file I am using is the following:

```
language: java
script:
    - gradle bundleRelease
```

but it seems to be ignored because `gradle bundleRelease` is never invoked. Instead I get the following output that suggests me that `gradle assemble` is invoked instead.

```
Using worker: worker-linux-8-1.bb.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-5

travis_fold:start:git.1
$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master git://github.com/mariosangiorgio/RateMyApp.git
[...]
mariosangiorgio/RateMyApp
Cloning into 'mariosangiorgio/RateMyApp'...
done.
travis_fold:end:git.1    
$ cd mariosangiorgio/RateMyApp
travis_fold:start:git.3
$ git checkout -qf 90faf4539c835136895ea92dd2bcc7da12ad1145
travis_fold:end:git.3
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_45
travis_fold:start:install
$ gradle assemble
[...]
The command "gradle assemble" failed and exited with 1 during install.

Your build has been stopped.
```

I read the [page linked in the documentation](http://blog.crowdint.com/2013/05/24/android-builds-on-travis-ci-with-gradle.html) but unfortunately it wasn't much helpful to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is mine `yaml` file which is building apk. But it should work also for library.

```
language: java
jdk: oraclejdk7
branches:
  only:
    - master
before_install:
  - chmod +x gradlew
  # Install base Android SDK
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
  - if [ `uname -m` = x86_64 ]; then sudo apt-get install -qq --force-yes libgd2-xpm ia32-libs ia32-libs-multiarch > /dev/null; fi
  - wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.0.5-linux.tgz
  - tar xzf android-sdk_r22.0.5-linux.tgz
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
  # install android build tools
  - wget https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r19.0.1-linux.zip
  - unzip build-tools_r19.0.1-linux.zip -d $ANDROID_HOME
  - mkdir -p $ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/
  - mv $ANDROID_HOME/android-4.4.2 $ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/19.0.1
  # Install required components.
  - echo yes | android update sdk --filter platform-tools --no-ui --force > /dev/null
  - echo yes | android update sdk --filter android-19 --no-ui --force > /dev/null
  - echo yes | android update sdk --filter extra-android-support --no-ui --force > /dev/null
  - echo yes | android update sdk --filter extra-android-m2repository --no-ui --force > /dev/null
install:
  - true
script:
  - TERM=dumb ./gradlew test assembleDebug
```

But be careful since this script doesn't push built artefact anywhere

Comment: Thank you! Can you please give me directions about something I can read to have TravisCI publish artifacts somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I got [an error message](https://travis-ci.org/mariosangiorgio/RateMyApp/builds/16812539). Do you have any idea of what may cause it?

Comment: Could you add `TERM=dumb` in the gradle line `- TERM=dumb ./gradlew bundleRelease`

Comment: Thanks, it has been extremely useful to debug what was going on. In my case the error was `failed to find target android-18` due to a version mismatch between the installed SDK and the one I told gradle to use to compile

Comment: Yeah, I'm using SDK 19 in my project. Great that you fixed it

Comment: The answer is outdated since Travis CI supports android natively now

Answer (score 3):

I use an [SDK installer](https://github.com/embarkmobile/android-sdk-installer/) script in the [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/austynmahoney/Hilt/blob/master/.travis.yml) for [Hilt](https://github.com/austynmahoney/Hilt).

```
language: java
jdk: oraclejdk7
before_install:
    # Install base Android SDK and components
    - sudo apt-get update -qq
    - sudo apt-get install -qq libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 expect
    - export COMPONENTS=build-tools-19.0.3,android-19,extra-android-support,extra-android-m2repository,extra-google-m2repository
    - export LICENSES=android-sdk-license-bcbbd656
    - curl -3L https://raw.github.com/embarkmobile/android-sdk-installer/version-2/android-sdk-installer | bash /dev/stdin --install=$COMPONENTS --accept=$LICENSES
    - source ~/.android-sdk-installer/env

install:
    # Without TERM=dumb, we get mangled output in the Travis console
    - TERM=dumb ./gradlew clean assemble -PdisablePreDex

script:
    - TERM=dumb ./gradlew check -PdisablePreDex
```

**EDIT:** Travis-CI has implemented Android as a first class citizen - http://blog.travis-ci.com/2014-05-07-android-build-support-now-in-beta/

Answer (score 1):

To address why you're seeing `gradle assemble` instead of `gradle bundleRelease`:

`gradle assemble` is invoked by default in the `install:` stage of Travis (see [Travis docs](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-configuration/#install) for description of stages, and [this note](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java/#Dependency-Management)).

Since you don't have an `install:` section of your script to override the default, Travis is invoking `gradle assemble`.

You can prevent this by adding the following lines, which tells Travis not to do anything during the install stage:

```
install:
    - true
```

I had [a similar issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1395#issuecomment-41917707), with Travis executing `gradle assemble` when I wanted it to execute `gradlew assembleDebug`.

So, for me, a complete working script (as of May 1, 2014 with [Android as a first class citizen](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1395#issuecomment-41817835)) is:

```
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk7

android:
  components:
    - build-tools-19.0.1

install:
    - true

script: TERM=dumb ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Thanks to Austyn Mahoney for clarifying this for me [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1395#issuecomment-41950488).

**EDIT**

As of May 8, 2014, Travis CI has removed the default `install:` stage for the Android beta, as discussed [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1395#issuecomment-42520643).  Therefore, you should now be able to remove the `install:` stage from your script, and Travis shouldn't execute `gradle assemble`.